# unix code for count of files in hourly basis

Tags: unix

I have a folder where xml files autogenerates in every hour. Please help me to find the count of xml generated in

a. past 24 hours

b. on hourly basis

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [`find` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find): it generates one line per result; and an easy way to count is to pipe the result to `wc -l` that will count then number of lines

a.: `-ctime-1` where create time is less than 1; `-type f` count only files; [optional `-name *.xml` I let you guess]

```
find /my/directory -ctime -1 -type f |wc -l
```

b.: same with `-cmin -60`

```
find /my/directory -cmin -60 -type f |wc -l
```

Enjoy and share